# How to do a split of a string

Tags: c, split

HI, I would like how to do a split of a string in c without #include

Comment: C does not have a real string type, so you will have to be more explicit about exactly how you want to fake strings and about how you want to represent the result.

Comment: Without #include *what*?  string.h?  Any header?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways of doing that, which I'll just explain and not write for you as this can only be a homework (or self-enhancement exercise, so the intent is the same).

- Either you split the string into multiple strings that you re-allocate into a multi-dimensional array,
- or you simply cut the string on separators and add terminal '\0' where appropriate and just copy the starting address of each sub-string to an array of pointers.

The approach for the splitting is similar in both cases, but in the second one you don't need to allocate any memory (but modify the original string), while in the first one you create safe copies of each sub-string.

You were not specific on the splitting, so I don't know if you wanted to cut on substrings, a single charater, or a list of potential separators, etc...

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. find the point you would like to split it
2. make two buffers large enough to contain data
3. strcpy() or do it manually (see example)

in this code I assume you have a string str[] and would like to split it at the first comma:

```
for(int count = 0; str[count] != '\0'; count++) {
    if(str[count] == ',')
        break;
}

if(str[count] == '\0')
    return 0;

char *s1 = malloc(count);
strcpy(s1, (str+count+1));                        // get part after

char *s2 = malloc(strlen(str) - count);           // get part before
for(int count1 = 0; count1 < count; count1++)
    s2[count1] = str[count1];
```

got it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have complete control of the function prototype, I'd do this (make this a single source file (**no #includes**) and compile, then link with the rest of the project)

If `#include <stddef.h>` is part of the "without #include" thing (but it shouldn't), then instead of `size_t`, use `unsigned long` in the code below

```
#include <stddef.h>
/* split of a string in c without #include */
/*
** `predst` destination for the prefix (before the split character)
** `postdst` destination for the postfix (after the split character)
** `src` original string to be splitted
** `ch` the character to split at
** returns the length of `predst`
**
** it is UB if
**     src does not contain ch
**     predst or postdst has no space for the result
*/
size_t split(char *predst, char *postdst, const char *src, char ch) {
    size_t retval = 0;
    while (*src != ch) {
        *predst++ = *src++;
        retval++;
    }
    *predst = 0;
    src++; /* skip over ch */
    while ((*postdst++ = *src++) != 0) /* void */;
    return retval;
}
```

Example usage

```
char a[10], b[42];
size_t n;
n = split(b, a, "forty two", ' ');
/* n is 5; b has "forty"; a has "two" */
```